# Is the process for SSL/TLS server key generation different on VMs?

Tags: 18.04, ssl, openssl, tls

For 3 of our company's servers, Bitsight is reporting that our Diffie-Hellman prime is very commonly used and is not safe. We've followed the directions here: https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html several times and it has worked with our other servers. However, these 3 do no update no matter what we do. One thing we did notice is that these 3 servers are all VMs. Each are on Ubunutu 18.04.6 LTS. Is there anything we haven't checked or could be missing that's keeping this value from updating?

Comment: Reviewers: This may refer to 18.04, but this is a generalized question about Webservers and DH parameters for SSL.  The problem with DH parameters is the WeakDH problem as linked by the admin.  It looks like OP hasn't taken the steps to properly resolve this, so I'm giving them the steps.  This isn't 18.04 or Ubuntu version specific.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the VMs vs. bare metal, or anything.

This is a result of your systems relying on precompiled DH keys in the web servers themselves - Apache, NGINX, etc. all have their own DH keys readily available precompiled.

The way to solve this is to generate your own DH params and then providing that for your configuration and telling the web servers to use those DH parameters.

To generate the dhparams:

`sudo openssl dhparam 2048 > /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem`

After this, you simply have to configure your webservers to use those.

For Apache 2.4.x, add this to your configuration for your sites where you configure your SSL certs:

`SSLOpenSSLConfCmd DHParameters "/etc/ssl/dhparam.pem"`

For NGINX, add this to your config where your SSL certs are configured:

`ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem`

---

Note you need to generate this on each system independently to break the warnings.

Industry Standard DHParam recommendation is 2048 bits.

---

Alternatively, configure your SSL ciphers to NOT use DH configuration directly.

Personally, I borrow cipher strings from [Mozilla's SSL Configuration generator](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/), and use this set of cipher strings from the Intermediate grade of ciphers, but strip out pure DH ciphers (so dhparams aren't an issue then).

The cipher string I utilize is this: `ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305` from the Intermediate configurations.  This is recommended by Mozilla for general-purpose server usages and when you don't need legacy support for old systems.  (See https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS for details)

We then specify this in the configurations for SSL ciphers.

For any Apache system of recent vintage (even in 18.04 or later), we specify this where you configure your SSL certs/settings for recommended settings (minus DHE ciphers, but including ECDHE ciphers which are elliptic curve ciphers):

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
```

For NGINX, these are the config lines to add to match standard recommendations:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
```

This will prevent your system(s) from using DHE ciphers (but not ECDHE ciphers which are not impacted by WeakDH) entirely, bypassing the `dhparam` problem entirely.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The dhparam.pem was already generated (and following your response has been regenerated) and SSLOpenSSLConfCmd was confirmed to still point to it and the apache2 service was restarted. We're still seeing the same prime order group in the ServerKeyExchange. I compared the SSL.conf config with other servers and they all have the same suite and dhparam.pem path. I've verified that the dhparam.pem file updates following generated and apache2 restart. We're still getting the same error. We suspect there is a stale config somewhere.

Comment: @KevinFoster do you have a reverse proxy anywhere in your network or a WAF or such that is before this server specifically?  Are you testing from inside or outside the network?  (18.04 remains EOL though, I STRONGLY recommend upgrading when you can to 20.04)

Comment: We do not have a reverse proxy anywhere in the network nor do we have a WAF in front of this server. We've tested inside the network using another OS on the same Hyper-V as well our other bare metal servers on the same subnet. We've tested offnet using Bitsight. All of which produce the same results.

Comment: Turns out we were using a deprecated SSL config file. 

"Custom DH parameters and an EC curve name for ephemeral keys, can also be added to end of the first file configured using SSLCertificateFile. This is supported in version 2.4.7 or later. Such parameters can be generated using the commands openssl dhparam and openssl ecparam. The parameters can be added as-is to the end of the first certificate file. Only the first file can be used for custom parameters, as they are applied independently of the authentication algorithm type."
https://shorturl.at/sBFKS